# Validación con javascript

Tags: javascript, formularios, condiciones

**Quiero saber como puedo mejorar mi código javascript para que quede más organizado**

Esta validación es solamente del campo nombre.

Tengo que validar algunos campos más y creo que no está muy bien organizado principalmente en con los IFs

```
const form = document.querySelector("#form-proyecto");
let nombre = form.nombre;
let solo_letras = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z]+$", "i");

form.addEventListener("submit", validar);
function validar(e) {
  validarNombre(e);
}

function validarNombre(e) {
  if (nombre.value == "" || nombre.value == null) {
   Swal.fire('Aviso','El campo nombre es obligatorio','error');
    e.preventDefault();
  } else {
    if (nombre.value.length < 3) {
        Swal.fire('Aviso','El campo nombre debe tener como mínimo 3 caracteres','error');
      e.preventDefault();
    } else {
      if (!solo_letras.test(nombre.value)) {
          Swal.fire('Aviso','Solo se aceptan letras en el campo nombre','error');
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

si solo llamas a una función entonces puede llamarla directamente.

```js
form.addEventListener("submit", validarNombre);
```

Luego para la función `validarNombre` estar repitiendo código muchas veces.

```js
function validarNombre(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); //lo ponemos antes que todo
  let msg;
  if (nombre.value == "" || nombre.value == null && nombre.value<3) {
   msg = 'El campo nombre es obligatorio y debe tener más de 3 letras';
   }else if (!solo_letras.test(nombre.value)) {
      msg = 'Solo se aceptan letras en el campo nombre';
   }
  Swal.fire('Aviso', msg, 'error');
}
```

Esta es mi forma de *reducir* el código que tienes, no es necesario declarar el `preventDefault()` siempre, solo una vez y tampoco es necesario crear la alerta para cada condición.

Comment: Tengo que llamar 9 campos, pero ya tengo una idea de como hacer. Muchas gracias